# fancy box Youtube video issues with Headers

Tags: ajax, wordpress, fancybox, same-origin-policy

I´m trying to load a video trough Fancybox. In my development server works like a charm but in the production server I get always the same error. It´s a WordPress Website

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n2Ks9FGj36Y&feature=youtu.be. Origin http://www.dgmedios.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I write the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to * in the server and nothing seems to work.

Any suggestion please? Thanks in advance.

D.

Comment: `I write the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to * ` : did you do this via php or else?

Comment: Hi. The website owner install NexGent and the plugin uses his own Fancybox file. I remove the duplicated and start working perfect. Was a Origin policy conflict in fact. Thanks for the help.